# Using ref into class and hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

A class react code written few years ago.

It code is using ref, calling another components function.

Like this.

origin code

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  processWindow = null;

  someFunction = () => {
    this.processWindow
  }

  render() {
    <ProgressWindow
       ref={ref => {
         this.processWindow = ref;
       }}
    />
```

It's works.

But start trouble after change class component to function component.

Another component convert to function component, nothing find any ref in origin component.

How I add something code to another component?

console.log(ref) from class component
[image]

console.log(ref) from function component
null

Comment: "But start trouble after change class component to function component." Where is the code? Can you provide reproducible example?

Comment: another component is class, works.

but, another component covert to function component, anything find ref in origin component.

Problem start after convert class to function.

Comment: Did you try [forwardRef](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/forwardRef#forwardref)

Comment: what does "other component" means here? question looks confusing to me. Can you refer by component name instead? "I converted `Login/ProgressWindow/some other component` into function component but `ref` above does not work after this"

Answer (score 0):

Does this help

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

function Login(props) {
  const processWindowRef = useRef();

  return (
    <ProgressWindow
      ref={ref => { processWindowRef.current = ref; }}
      // can try 
      // ref={processWindowRef}
     />
  );
});
```

More about [useRef](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef) in the beta docs

Hope it helps

Comment: I know best way is login.js convert to function component.
But I cant convert. Only way is covert another component.